# Trouble calculating totals with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been struggling to learn jQuery lately. I have finally got jQuery to total my form data at the bottom, but I need to add another piece to the puzzle.

Currently it takes the amount the end user inputs and multiplies the total by 4 which is the price of the apples. I need to make it so the form will reduce the amount by $2 if they order 3 or more apples. (Buy 1 apple for $4 or 3 for $10)

Live version: http://jsfiddle.net/sbdthru/cSfmy/

```
    var $form = $('#apple-order'),
        $summands = $form.find('.apple'),
        $sumDisplay = $('#total');

    $form.delegate('.apple', 'change', function ()
    {
        var sum = 0;
        $summands.each(function ()
        {
            var value = Number($(this).val());
            if (!isNaN(value)) sum += value;
        });

        $sumDisplay.text(sum * 4);
    });
```

Comment: What exactly do you have problems with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a modifier that tests the sum:

```
var modifier = sum >= 3 ? 2 : 0;
$sumDisplay.text(sum * 4 - modifier);
```